# How to make a vector that controls the size of two arrays

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

In MIPS, I have this code and I don't know how to make it so that there are to arrays whose sizes are Controled by a vector. Like-- "Please enter the size of the vector." and you choose five and so the arrays sizes are five. "Enter in the numbers for Array 1". You enter `10 10 10 10 10`. Then it asks you to enter in the size for array 2. lastly it shows the the sum and averages for both array 1 and array 2. Heres what I have so far.

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter 10 Elements: \n"
avg: .asciiz "Average of these numbers is: "
sum: .float 0
count: .float 10
.text
main:
#size of the vector using prompt
la $a0 prompt
li $v0 4
syscall



li $t1, 40   # t1 has count
li $t2, 0   # t2 is iterator
l.s $f12, sum   # t3 has sum
while: bge $t2, $t1, end
   li $v0, 6
   syscall

       add.s $f12, $f12, $f0
       addi $t2, $t2, 4
       b while
end:

la $a0 avg
li $v0, 4
syscall


   lwc1 $f10, count
div.s $f12, $f12, $f10

li $v0, 2
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

li $v0, 2
lwc1, $f12 sum
```

Comment: I messed up and meant to tag it as MIPS, not c++. Sorry.

Comment: It's all good : ) What do you mean by "two arrays whose sizes are controlled by a vector"? I haven't used MIPS in a while but I would like to help.

Comment: Alright thank you. What I'm trying to do is Write an assembly program that first, prompts the user for the size of the vector and then, prompts
the user to enter two lists of numbers or vectors from the keyboard. It will then display the original vectors along with their sum, average.                           Does that help?

Comment: Prompts the user for the size of the vector because the size of the vector would be the size of the arrays. Vector size = "User input"------ Array1 size = "vector size" same with Array2. Does that make sense?

Comment: So `vector size = array1 size = array2 size`?

Comment: I think so? Say it asks you to input the size of the vector and you choose 5. The it asks you to Enter the numbers for Array1. You would enter in 5 numbers because you choose 5 for the vector. Same with Array2 that you would only enter in 5 numbers because of the vector.

Comment: Got it. I'm catching up on my MIPS right now, hopefully I'll have an answer in an hour or two, or someone else might come along and provide valuable insight.

Comment: Thank You! I've been stuck on this so long and came to this site because I hope someone would be able to help me. That also why my question was badly structured because this was my first time asking a question. Should I move this to a chat?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little while to refresh my memory of MIPS. I wrote up a somewhat small program that asks the user for the size of the vector. Using that size it then dynamically allocates two integer arrays and prompts the user to fill said arrays. Once the arrays have been filled, via user input, the program then prints the first array followed by its sum, then the second array followed by its sum.

I noticed that your code uses floating point numbers. Since I don't know if this is a homework assignment or school project, I thought I'd let you figure out how to convert the below code to use floating point numbers. Also, I purposely left out the code to calculate the average for the same reason (but I did leave comments where the code could possibly be added). Modifying the program to use floating point numbers and adding an average calculation shouldn't be to hard. Let me know if you need further assistance in the comments section of this answer.

Sorry about the spacing of some of the comments in the code, copying from the program I used didn't go so well.

#### Vector Program

```c
# ====== DATA SEGMENT ====== #
    .data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter Size of the Vector:\n"
enter:  .asciiz "Enter the "
first:  .asciiz " numbers in the first array:\n"
second: .asciiz " numbers in the second array:\n"
sum:    .asciiz "Sum of these numbers is: "
avg:    .asciiz "Average of these numbers is: "
open:   .asciiz "[ "
close:  .asciiz " ]\n"
comma:  .asciiz ", "
lf: .asciiz "\n"
a1: .word   0   # first array
a2: .word   0   # second array

#   syscall variables
printi: .word   1   # print_int
printf: .word   2   # print_float
prints: .word   4   # print_string
readi:  .word   5   # read_int
readf:  .word   6   # read_float
sbrk:   .word   9
exit:   .word   10

# ====== TEXT SEGMENT ====== #
    .text
main:
    # initialize and describe registers
    li $s0, 0       # vector size
    li $s1, 0       # first array's sum
    li $s2, 0       # second array's sum
    li $s6, 0       # temporary sum store
    li $s7, 0       # temporary array address store
    li $t9, 0       # loop iterator
    
    # prompt for vector size
    la $a0, prompt
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    
    # get vector size integer into $s0
    lw $v0, readi
    syscall
    add $s0, $zero, $v0     # store vector size in $s0
    
    # dynamically allocate first array
    mul $t1, $s0, 4     # put size * 4 in $t1
    add $a0, $zero, $t1 # put mul result in $a0
    lw $v0, sbrk        # allocate size * 4 bytes in memory
    syscall
    sw $v0, a1      # put address returned by sbrk in a1
    
    # dynamically allocate second array
    lw $v0, sbrk        # allocate another size * 4 bytes in memory
    syscall
    sw $v0, a2      # put address returned by sbrk in a2
    
    # prompt for first array elements
    jal print_enter
    la $a0, first
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    
    # fill the first array and calculate sum
    lw $s7, a1
    jal array_fill
    add $s1, $zero, $s6     # put first sum in $s1
    
    # prompt for second array elements
    jal print_enter
    la $a0, second
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    
    # fill the second array and calculate sum
    lw $s7, a2
    jal array_fill
    add $s2, $zero, $s6     # put second sum in $s2
    
    # print the first array
    lw $s7, a1
    jal print_array
    
    # print the sum of the first array
    la $s6, ($s1)
    jal print_sum
    
    # TODO: Add array1 average calculation and output
    
    # print the second array
    lw $s7, a2
    jal print_array
    
    # print the sum of the second array
    la $s6, ($s2)
    jal print_sum
    
    # TODO: Add array2 average calculation and output
    
    b end
    
print_enter:
    # print "Enter the "
    la $a0, enter
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    # print the number of elements to enter
    add $a0, $zero, $s0
    lw $v0, printi
    syscall
    jr $ra

array_fill:
    la $s6, ($zero)     # set tmp sum to 0
    la $t9, ($zero)     # set iterator to 0
array_fill_for: bge $t9, $s0, end_array_fill
    # get integer from user
    lw $v0, readi
    syscall
    
    sw $v0, ($s7)       # store integer at current array index
    add $s6, $s6, $v0   # keep a running sum in $s6
    
    add $s7, $s7, 4     # get address of next array element
    add $t9, $t9, 1     # increment iterator
    b array_fill_for
end_array_fill:
    jr $ra
    
print_array:
    # print opening bracket of array
    la $a0, open
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    
    la $t9, ($zero)     # set iterator to 0
    add $t0, $s0, -1    # loop over size-1 elements
print_array_for: bge $t9, $t0, end_print_array
    # print array element at current index
    lw $a0, ($s7)
    lw $v0, printi
    syscall
    # print a seperating comma
    la $a0, comma
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    
    add $s7, $s7, 4     # get address of next array element
    add $t9, $t9, 1     # increment iterator
    b print_array_for
end_print_array:
    # print last index of array without comma
    lw $a0, ($s7)
    lw $v0, printi
    syscall
    
    # print closing bracket of array
    la $a0, close
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    jr $ra
    
print_sum:
    # print the sum greeting
    la $a0, sum
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    
    # print the sum that's in $s6
    la $a0, ($s6)
    lw $v0, printi
    syscall
    
    # print a line feed
    la $a0, lf
    lw $v0, prints
    syscall
    jr $ra

end:
    lw $v0, exit
    syscall
```

#### Test Input/Output

```
Enter Size of the Vector:
4
Enter the 4 numbers in the first array:
1
2
3
4
Enter the 4 numbers in the second array:
5
6
7
8
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
Sum of these numbers is: 10
[ 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
Sum of these numbers is: 26

-- program is finished running --
```

#### Some Links I Found Helpful

- [MIPS Instruction
  Reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)
- [MIPS Dynamic Memory Allocation using
  sbrk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588905/mips-dynamic-memory-allocation-using-sbrk)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I didn't respond sooner I had to help my sisters and I had college. Thank you for everything you did.