# How do you make a vector that controls array size in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I have the following MIPS code. I don't know how to make it such that there are two arrays with a size controlled by a vector.

For instance, the user would enter a size (let's say `5`). The arrays sizes would then be set to `5`. Then the user could enter in numbers for array one, say `10 10 10 10 10`, and then for array 2. Finally, the program will display the sum and averages for both arrays.

This is the code so far:

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Enter 10 Elements: \n"

avg: .asciiz "Average of these numbers is: "

sum: .float 0

count: .float 10

.text

main:

---size of the vector using prompt

la $a0 prompt
li $v0 4
syscall



li $t1, 40   # t1 has count

li $t2, 0   # t2 is iterator

l.s $f12, sum   # t3 has sum

while: bge $t2, $t1, end
   li $v0, 6
   syscall

add.s $f12, $f12, $f0
addi $t2, $t2, 4
b while
end:

la $a0 avg

li $v0, 4

syscall


lwc1 $f10, count

div.s $f12, $f12, $f10

li $v0, 2

syscall

li $v0, 10

syscall

li $v0, 2

lwc1, $f12 sum
```

Comment: I don't see any explanation of what the problem with the current code is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a vector that controls the size of two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881670/how-to-make-a-vector-that-controls-the-size-of-two-arrays)